# Removing DATE from middle of the Files names in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed

i am trying to remove the DATE from the following file names in unix

```
DMART_D02_20191101_contracts_ifrs9.csv
DMART_D02_20191101_contrannual_ifrs9.csv
```

**Expected Result**

```
DMART_D02_contracts_ifrs9.csv
DMART_D02_contrannual_ifrs9.csv
```

I have tried the below command but its not working.

```
sed -e 's/KKDAR_D02_[0-9]*/KKDAR_D02/g' sourcefolder > destinationfolder
```

Can some one please help me out

Comment: The pattern contains KKDAR_ that doesn't match DMART_

Comment: When you ask a question, "its not working" is not a good description.  You should show us a sample input, a desired output, and what output you are getting right now.  See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `DMART_D02_[0-9]+_.*_ifrs9\.csv`

Comment: Perhaps `rename 's/_[0-9]{8}_/_/' *.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are manipulating filemames, not the texts in the files, you will want to say something like:

```
for f in sourcefolder/*.csv; do
    newname=$(sed 's/.*\///; s/_[0-9]\{8\}_/_/' <<< "$f")
    cp -p -- "$f" "destinationfolder/$newname"
done
```

If you want to change the filenames in-place, without copying in the new directory, please try instead:

```
for f in sourcefolder/*.csv; do
    newname=$(sed 's/_[0-9]\{8\}_/_/' <<< "$f")
    mv -- "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Please note I'm assuming you are working with `bash`. If you are working on other shell, please let me know.